# Wordpress taxonomy loop pagination - Older post link not showing

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, series

I have the following loop, which is suppose to pull all taxonomy called series and the post under it. It works fine but the problem is it is not not showing Older posts link. I manually go to second page Newer post links shows up. Any idea what am I missing?

```
                <?php
                $page = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
                $per_page = 5;
                $offset = ( $page-1 ) * $per_page;
                $args = array( 'number' => $per_page, 'offset' => $offset, 'hide_empty' => 0,'paged' => $page);
                $terms = get_terms('series',$args);

            foreach ($terms as $term) {
              $wpq = array ('taxonomy'=>'series','term'=>$term->slug);
              $myquery = new WP_Query ($wpq);
              $article_count = $myquery->post_count;
              echo "<h3 class=\"term-heading\" id=\"".$term->slug."\">";
              echo $term->name;
              echo "</h3>";
              if ($article_count) {
                echo "<ul>";
                while ($myquery->have_posts()) : $myquery->the_post();
                  echo "<li><a href=\"".get_permalink()."\">".$post->post_title."</a></li>";
                endwhile;
                echo "</ul>";
              }   } ?>

        <div class="clear"></div>
            <p class="previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '&larr; Older posts', 'ari' ) ); ?></p>
            <p class="next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts &rarr;', 'ari' ) ); ?></p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this (I've tested), paged is not working good with offset, which is better for get_terms() (but still useful to get_query_var('paged')), also change "category" to your desired term.

```
 <?php
 $page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
 $per_page = 4;
 $offset = ( $page-1 ) * $per_page;
 $args = array( 'number' => $per_page, 'offset' => $offset, 'hide_empty' => 0);
 $terms = get_terms('category', $args);

 foreach ($terms as $term){
   $wpq = array ('taxonomy'=>'category','term'=>$term->slug);
   $myquery = new WP_Query ($wpq);
   $article_count = $myquery->post_count;
   echo "<h3 class=\"term-heading\" id=\"".$term->slug."\">";
   echo $term->name;
   echo "</h3>";
   if ($article_count){
     echo "<ul>";
     while ($myquery->have_posts()) : $myquery->the_post();
     echo "<li><a href=\"".get_permalink()."\">".$post->post_title."</a></li>";
     endwhile;
     echo "</ul>";
     }   
   } ?>
```

Comment: I removed offset, still it is not showing the older post link.